# unable to use the string "execute(" in GET or POST

Tags: php, security

If I use the URL www.mysite.com/?test=execute( the $_GET array will always be emtpy. I noticed this when trying to submit a form with the string "execute(" in, it would not submit.

This includes POST and GET, it does not accept the string "execute(". Is this security feature on the server as it works fine on my local computer?

Comment: Wow, I get the same thing on my website. Strange.

Comment: `?p=execute(` gives 403 Forbidden. `?p=readdir(` gives 501 Method Not Implemented. Everything else I've tried so far is fine.

Comment: Oh, the encoded `%28` version triggers it too. Oddly enough, putting a space between it does seem to work fine: `?p=execute%20(` So I really have no clue. It looks like some kind of poorly implemented security feature for sure.

Comment: Looks like a server-wide filter which excludes PHP keywords? http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.configuration.php

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce, even after having set `filter.default="unsafe_raw"`. Perhaps you could share your config file, both Apache and PHP, and include which versions you use.

Comment: How about the applied default filters and loaded modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have mod_security installed in Apache.

Comment: Bingo! Yes it was mod_security. I followed the instructions here to disable http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/mod_security-nightmares-75078.html#post350851